# Replacing a variable inside a netCDF file

Tags: python, netcdf4

I have a netCDF file with a variable `A` having the following characteristics:

```
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 Mlail(month, y, x)
units: -
long_name: monthly low veg lai
missing_value: 1.00000002004e+20
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (12, 1, 1)
filling off
Mlail = 
[[[ 2.01562]]
[[ 2.00781]]
[[ 2.10156]]
[[ 2.28906]]
[[ 2.80469]]
[[ 3.02344]]
[[ 2.91406]]
[[ 2.77344]]
[[ 2.65625]]
[[ 2.33594]]
[[ 2.14844]]
[[ 2.0625 ]]]
```

I wish to replace those value by let say : `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12`

For that I tried the following command:

```
dataset['Mlail'] = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]]
```

But it's not working and I alwayz got the return error message:

```
TypeError: 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset' object does not support item assignment
```

Does anyone knows how to do that?

Here is my code

```
import netCDF4
dataset = netCDF4.Dataset('surfclim_AmpleroFluxnet.nc')
print (dataset.variables.keys())
import numpy
print ("Mlail = \n", dataset.variables['Mlail'][:])
dataset['Mlail'] = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your original code is trying to replace the variable object with the list of values. What you want to do is replace the values on the variable, which you can do with a slice (the `[:]`), just like you do when you print out the values). You also need to make sure you open the file for modification (with the `'a'` flag). So your code would become:

```
import netCDF4
import numpy

dataset = netCDF4.Dataset('surfclim_AmpleroFluxnet.nc', 'a')
print (dataset.variables.keys())
print ("Mlail = \n", dataset.variables['Mlail'][:])
var = dataset['Mlail']
var[:] = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]]
```